# Change name of main row Rails in JSON

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

So i have a json:

```
{
  "code": "Q0934X",
  "name": "PIDBA",
  "longlat": "POINT(23.0 33.0)",
  "altitude": 33
}
```

And i want to change the column `code` to `Identifier`

The wished output is this

```
{
  "Identifier": "Q0934X",
  "name": "PIDBA",
  "longlat": "POINT(23.0 33.0)",
  "altitude": 33
}
```

How can i do in the shortest way? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - do you have a JSON column in your database? Or just some json string in your code?

Comment: Just String in my code

Answer (score 2):

It appears that both "the json" you have and your desired result are JSON strings. If the one you have is `json_str` you can write:

```
json = JSON.parse(json_str).tap { |h| h["Identifier"] = h.delete("code") }.to_json
```

```
puts json
  #=> {"name":"PIDBA","longlat":"POINT(23.0 33.0)","altitude":33,"Identifier":"Q0934X"}
```

Note that [Hash#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete) returns the value of the key being removed.

Comment: If it's a json hash there are no symbols, should be h["identifier"] = h.delete("code")

Comment: @Joel, thank you for the correction. While I had tested this with `.to_json` at the end, I somehow omitted that in my answer. Note that with `to_json`, `h[:Identifier]` does work. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) is an option.

The following seems to work for me (ruby 2.6):

```
json = JSON.parse(json_str).transform_keys { |k| k === 'code' ? 'Identifier' : k }.to_json
```

But this may work for Ruby 3.0 onwards (if I've understood the docs):

```
json = JSON.parse(json_str).transform_keys({ 'code': 'Identifier' }).to_json
```